# What simple constructions / algorithms for sorting and selection networks from k-sorters (k>2) are known?

Tags: ordering

There are simple algorithms to construct sorting networks from 2-sorters, e.g. Batcher's [bitonic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter) sorters and [Pairwise sorting networks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_sorting_network).

How can one construct general sorters with a low number of $k$-sorters, $k\gt 2$?
Is there a similar result for *select* / *partial sorting*, say, the $\sqrt n$th element or the top $\sqrt n$ ones?

Comment: Currently looking at [Parker, B.; Parberry, I: "Constructing Sorting Networks from k-sorters", Information Processing Letters, Vol. 33, No. 3, pp. 157-162, 1989](https://web.archive.org/web/20110816184155/http://larc.unt.edu/ian/pubs/ksorters.pdf), cudos [Ian Parberry](https://web.archive.org/web/20110816183340/https://larc.unt.edu/ian/research/sortingnetworks/)

Comment: (Not seen previously: Dobrokhotova-Maikova, N.; Kozachinskiy, A.;
Podolskii, V.: [Towards Simpler Sorting Networks
and Monotone Circuits for Majority](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.12270v1.pdf) - not simple)

Comment: (Shell-sort may be suggesting itself.)